# Java: Difference between initializing by constructor and by static method?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, workflow, bukkit

This might just be a question of personal taste and workflow, but in case it's more than that, I feel I should ask anyway.

In Java, what differences are there between creating an instance via constructor and via a static method (which returns the instance)? For example, take this bit of code from a project I'm working on (written up by hand at time of posting, so some shortcuts and liberties are taken):

```
Plugin main;
Map<int, int> map;

public Handler(Plugin main) {
    this.main = main;
}

public static Handler init(Plugin main) {
    Handler handler = new Handler(main);
    handler.createMap();
}

public void createMap() {
    this.map = Maps.newHashMap();
}
```

In cases like this, what would the difference be between using

```
Handler handler = new Handler(this);
```

and

```
Handler handler = Handler.init(this);
```

in the Plugin class, besides the fact that `createMap()` runs only in the latter because it's not called in the constructor?

To clarify, in this case, `Plugin` is considered the main class.

I know enough Java syntax to be able to write intermediate-level plugins, but not enough about Java itself to know the difference between these two ways of doing this.

EDIT: For instance, the `Maps` class that I used to create the `Map` uses a static factory method (I hope I'm using that term correctly) called using the class instead of an object.

Comment: Sorry; SO posted before I was done typing it! Must have hit Tab by accident, and didn't realize it until I tried hitting Enter to insert a newline. But I'm glad that people were able to read and reply to it before I could finish typing it, though the info given at the time was almost nil B-)

Comment: "written up by hand at time of posting" - you can always test code samples in [ideone](http://ideone.com/) (The "syntax highlighting" editor for them wouldn't be bad for creating those in the first place if it didn't insist on indenting with tabs.)

Comment: @millimoose True. Although I meant something more along the lines of "if I accidentally fail to convey what I mean, it's because I'm writing this off the top of my head". But +1 for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is a static factory method is more flexible. It can have all sorts of ways to return an instance. It can do other side stuff. It can have a more descriptive name. It can be invoked by its simple name (e.g. `foo(args)`) by static import or inheritance.

The constructor call is more certain - the caller knows exactly what's happening - a new instance of that exact class is created.

Comment: +1. I would add that a static factory method has an option to return an instance of a different concrete class, which can be very useful in some circumstances

Comment: Accepted. This is the type of answer I'm looking for. Nishant's answer is indeed helpful and informative, but I'm looking more for differences than advantages/disadvantages. Either way, both are helpful. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

There are both advantages and disadvantages of static factory methods.

**Advantages**

- Descriptive, meaningful names.
- When invoked they can decide whether to return a new instance
- They can return an object of any subtype of the return type
- They reduce the verbosity of creating parameterized type instances

**Disadvantages**

- If you provide only static factory methods, classes without public or protected constructors cannot be subclassed
- They are not readily distinguishable from other static methods

*Source: Effective Java, Second Ed.*

Comment: the #4 advantage no longer holds in java 7 which introduced diamond inference to solve that very problem.